# For responsiveness testing why https://material.io/resizer/ is not taking my url

Tags: google-signin

I have tested my site with google chrome  audits tool and with google chrome extension 'Responsive Web Design Tester'. With them my site is fully responsive. But When I test my site with https://material.io/resizer, it's not taking my url and says "Heads up!
The resizer is a tool for viewing non-Google websites using material design responsive UI breakpoints. The resizer will not ask for account information—you don't need to enter it when using this tool."
I have to test my site with it, because it is required.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDecg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. I was using `http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/learn`

But when I have made it secured(`https://`), then it's working fine. So the new url is `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/learn`

So, it was only for the security reason. My site's content is same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Chrome and make sure you are logged into your Gmail account. It will work then ;-)

Comment: Sorry, not working your suggestion.I used http://  but when  I try with https:// then it's working & it's showing my site is responsive.